# What happens when one planet "lands" on another?

Tags: planets, rogue-planets

Imagine, if you will, an Earth-like planet orbiting a Sol-like star.  Now imagine that, from somewhere outside the solar system, a rogue planet, rocky and of roughly the same size and mass of the first planet, enters the solar system on a trajectory that eventually takes it so close to the first planet that they end up touching one another.  What happens?

I was thinking that if both planets are spinning on their axes, they're going to rub against each other and potentially cancel each others' spin.  Would their gravitational pulls eventually merge them into a larger rocky planet?  How long would that take?  If the Earth-like planet was inhabited, what would the inhabitants experience (after the panic subsided)?

Comment: Is this a glancing blow or a full-on collision?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8N2y1Nk.gifv

Comment: What happens?  Go outside and [look up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_impact_hypothesis).

Comment: @King I see we had the same idea =)

Comment: everybody dies.

Comment: When you consider that according to classic science, the meteor that killed the dinosaurs was only 9 to 12 miles across (or maybe [even just 2.5 to 3.7 miles across](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2008/04/080410-sea-meteorites.html)), you can easily reason that a mass the size of a planet would probably kill you if it even only came *close*, and at some close enough point everything would die really, really fast.

Comment: Sounds more like a decaying orbit rather than a simple collision.

Comment: Reminds me of the [Melancholia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1527186/) movie.

Comment: "what would the inhabitants experience (after the panic subsided)?" - Smug satisfaction that their panic was justified, judging by the answers...

Comment: **land** (verb) - to be interrupted in the quest for terminal velocity. -- as euphemisms go, I *like* it!

Comment: This is a great fit for Worldbuilding! I would *really* like a story about doom and destruction on a planetary level, where planets are skimming against each other and throwing dust, buildings and mountains into space.

Comment: At planetary scales, solid matter, like planets do not act like "solids" as we normally expect.  Rather, they act more like liquids.  So two planets will act more like two drops of water, that are also stretched toawrds each other because of their mutual gravity.

Comment: @King-Ink I was a bit disappointed that no new moon formed from that collision...

Comment: It's basically total liquidation of the planet's surface. Nothing survives.

Comment: @2012rcampion Now you got me wondering if there might have been life before the giant impact and if any traces would be left of it.

Comment: The results of this surely defines the exact opposite of "world building" (unless you define 'building' in a very very very long-term sense!)

Comment: "what would the inhabitants experience (after the panic subsided)?"... proof of life after Death, apparently. Got to be , if any are capable of observing anything.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Your planet is screwed.

As was mentioned in comments, the [Giant Impact Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_impact_hypothesis) details a very similar situation, as Earth collides with another body of slightly smaller size at some angle of roughly 45°, so neither of the two are totally destroyed.

In a more direct impact, the centers of both bodies will collide and fuse, while excess material will be thrown off in one or more tails. [Eiland et al. (2013)](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1307/1307.7062.pdf) presented interesting models with one and two tails:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, if the planets collide at a more oblique angle, a disk may form:

[image]

These are simulations that result in material being ejected into orbit, thus forming a moon - the same thing that happened with Earth. In a completely direct impact, this may not happen; the two bodies could be destroyed. However, your scenario will most likely lead to a glancing blow and a disk. Note that in the first simulation only, each planet is spinning in the opposite direction as the other.

See also [Stevenson (1987)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1987AREPS..15..271S&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf) for a thorough theoretical treatment, which also explains how collision timescales differ based on different impactor masses:

[image]

That said, things might be different here. The incoming planet may be moving much quicker than the other body was in the Giant Impact Hypothesis, meaning that both bodies could be completely destroyed.

More cool (colorful!) simulation images can be found in [Canup (2003)](http://lasp.colorado.edu/%7Eespoclass/ASTR_5835_2013_Files/2013_10_29_Canup.Moon.Icarus.2004.pdf), which should give you a better idea of the temperatures reached during such collisions (about $\sim10^4$ Kelvin is possible!).

As I mentioned [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34583/could-it-be-possible-for-two-planets-to-collide-and-not-kill-everything/34587#34587), death may come because of these high temperatures, which will heat even the deepest layers of both planets. Life can't run and hide underground.

Comment: Good answer, and good choice of visuals from the Eiland paper! I was going to sketch something along those lines for my answer, but I probably can't improve on that in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: @type_outcast If you were going to sketch something, you have my deepest respect. I'm *terrible* at drawing; computer simulations make everything easier.

Comment: Especially when it's someone *else's* computer simulations.

Comment: I'm at a loss for which answer between these two is the one to select as "the answer."  I'm down to flipping a mental coin.

Comment: +1: Also worth noting for the non-physic community here, that this kind of interaction between planetary masses produces an incredible amount of residual energy in the form of heat.  So everything not hundreds/thousands of miles deep would burn and melt.  IE., there's no riding this out in some hardened bunker.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I made of note of that.

Comment: The *minimum* velocity for such an impact is the sum of the two planet's escape velocities.  The impact velocity can range to any velocity above that.  For the Earth, this velocity is 11.2 km/sec so they will hit with quite a bit of speed.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, if I remember correctly from stuff I've read about Earth - Theia impact, the crust and mantle of the Earth were completely melted.  Any standing water was vaporized.  Since the outer core was a liquid, essentially the only solids remaining in the system were the inner cores of the two bodies.  Since those have a temperature hotter than the surface of the Sun, you might as well say everything burns or melts.

Comment: @Jim2b In that case yes, but Theia was about the size of Mars.  A smaller planetiod and/or a more glancing contact (which the OP is actually supposing) wouldn't necessarily melt the entire mantle.  That was why I qualified it.

Answer (score 43):

## Everyone Dies

I assume the planets are on a "gentle" (shallow) approach to one another, which seems to match your description of "eventually takes it so close [that] they end up touching". There *will* be panic as the planets draw nearer.

Everyone will die; it's just a question of when and how.

## Tidal forces

As the planets approach, their mutual gravitational acceleration (doubled!) will pull them together and accelerate them to even higher relative speeds. The first problem is, the gravitational acceleration will not be uniform: the "near" pieces of the planets will feel a stronger pull than the "far" pieces, and this effect will be very pronounced.

It will cause great earthquakes and incredible ocean tides (and tsunamis), which will obliterate anything within a few hundred kilometers of a coastline. It will also destroy [key infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukushima_Daiichi_nuclear_disaster).

The atmospheres of both planets will be easily affected, causing weather patterns of a far greater magnitude than anything we know as both atmospheres will be pulled toward the center of mass of the two planets.

## Roche Limit

If anyone is still alive after all of the above, this last bit should do them in.

**Edit:** *Fixed math (and included steps!) Thanks to MadBender for the catch!*

The [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit) is the distance (radius) within which a celestial body (like a planet) can no longer hold itself together via its own gravity, and is then pulled apart by the gravitational tidal forces I introduced, above. The Roche limit (*d*) for rigid bodies<sup>1</sup> $\, m$ and $M$ (your twin Earths), looks like this:

$$d = R_m \left( 2 \cdot \frac{\rho_M}{\rho_m} \right)^{1/3}$$

$\rho_M / \rho_m$ is the ratio of densities of both planets. Since they are identical, their density ratio will be 1/1, thus:

$$d = R_m \left( 2 \cdot \frac{1}{1} \right)^{1/3} \approx 1.26 R_m$$
$$d \approx 1.26 \times 6\,371\text{ km} \approx 8\,027\text{ km}$$

As the two planets come within the Roche limit, the effects from the previous section will have already had catastrophic results, and started to elongate the planets. The difference is, that near the Roche boundary, gravity won't be enough to hold the planets together.

The overall mass stays the same, but the planets are literally torn to pieces. The atmospheres and oceans more or less go without a fight (see previous section), but the solid pieces will come bit by bit, and the (now very chaotic) motions will result in more impacts, which will continually pulverize the pieces until there isn't much left but a ring of debris around the star, almost certainly with no survivors.

What actually kills the remaining inhabitants is somewhat a matter of chance, but could be:

- Direct impact or secondary impact forces
- Suffocation/decompression as the atmosphere is pulled towards the center of mass but your tiny planetoid carries on a different trajectory. Or, the atmosphere simply gets thinner as the mass of your planetoid is too weak to retain it at sufficient density to support human life.

## Other effects

- The [magnetic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth's_magnetic_field) of both planets will combine, quite likely in a way that would reduce the effectiveness of the magnetosphere, allowing cosmic rays to bombard the inhabitants, causing an increase in radiation sickness and cancers, however I don't think anyone will live long enough for that.

---

## Notes

1. Of course the Earth isn't completely rigid. However, all of the liquid and gases would already have been pulled and squeezed into the gnarliest surf anyone has ever seen.

Comment: Good answer. Given the amount of damage that earthquakes cause to humans, and how much smaller those are than anything like any part of the planet being sucked into space, I think it's pretty safe to say that practically any inhabitant will be churned to death before the planets start ripping away the atmospheres and oceans.

Comment: Yikes, the image of living on a world mid-breakup due to the Roche limit as you outlined is terrifying!

Comment: According to the formula from wikipedia (the one for liquid bodies), Roche limit for two Earths is about 15500 km between their centers (not 6.38 mil km) and 3000 km between their surfaces. The planets will disintegrate in the very last moments before collision

Comment: Aside from any calculation, it should be intuitive that the moon (363000km away at perigee) hasn't broken up (in fact there's loose regolith on the surface) and therefore isn't inside the Earth's Roche limit.

Comment: The Roche limit being out by a factor of roughly 1,000 may be due to the linked Wikipedia article giving measurements in metres rather than kilometres.

Comment: And don't forget the heat.  I know it's obvious, but non-physics folks don't always know about the heat...

Comment: How long would this all take?

Comment: @MadBender et al.: Good catch. Thank you! It looks like I typed in 1000 * radius of the Earth rather than the Roche limit, which is of course completely bonkers, especially given that I *did* the math. I will fix once I'm back at a real computer (an hour or two).

Comment: OK, I've fixed the Roche limit section. @corsiKa Good question, and a complex one at that. I'll give that some thought and if I can sum it up in less than a hundred words or so, I'll edit my answer. And RBarryYoung, indeed, I'd imagine physicists would have been trying to warn people about Bi-Global Warming for decades, without avail.

Answer (score 11):

**Total destruction**

With the Earth's current orbit, the planet will have a [velocity at infinity](http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.no/2013/03/what-heck-is-vinf.html) of between $12.5km/s$ and $72 km/s$, depending on the direction of which it hits. (It has an even higher velocity if it comes from outside of the solar system). Is this enough energy to destroy both planets into small pieces?

Assuming the other planet is similar to the Earth too, we can use [gravitational binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy) to answer that question. The combined energy required to totally destroy them is $4.5 · 10^{32}J$. The energy added from the slowest impact is $4.7 \cdot 10^{32}J$. So both planets will be turned into molten gravel.

Comment: This will be an inelastic collision, so molten gravel, please ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Ok, I amend that.

Comment: There's no reason to cap it at 72km/s as this is a rogue, not a body from within the system.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Why not? That is Earth's orbital velocity plus the velocity of a planet going in the exact opposite direction at solar system escape velocity

Comment: And I disagree on total destruction.  You're right that the impact exceeds the binding energy of the two bodies but that's not the whole story.  First, much of the energy will become heat rather than flying fragments and you can't just add the two binding energies because not only do the planets need to fly apart but they need to fly away from each other.

Comment: @Hohmannfan A rogue object from outside the system could already have velocity, not just Vinf from the fall.  (And, in fact, to score a head-on hit it **must** have a velocity of it's own or it would hit the sun instead.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel About destruction, I am just thinking that if a collision involves enough energy to theoretically rip both objects apart, the outcome is pretty destructive anyway

Comment: @LorenPechtel "To score a head-on hit it *must* have a velocity of it's own or it would hit the sun instead." Wrong. If it has a Vinf of zero, orbit is parabolic. It's possible for a parabolic orbit to have a non-zero perihelion.

Comment: @HopDavid How?  If an object starts from infinity and falls it's going to go to the sun.  Yes, it could hit the Earth on the way in but that would be a side impact, not head on.  A non-zero perihelion requires a velocity normal to the direction to the sun.

Comment: When question says "on a trajectory that eventually takes it so close to the first planet that they end up touching one another", it sounds like OP is after minimal touch velocity, possibly after a few brakeing slingshots around the gas giants. And definitely not a head on collision.

Comment: @LorenPechtel If perihelion velocity is more than escape velocity you have a hyperbolic orbit with a Vinf > 0. If perihelion velocity is equal to escape, you have a Vinf=0, and the trajectory is parabolic. If perihelion velocity is less than escape, you have an elliptical orbit about the sun. This is very basic orbital mechanics stuff.

Comment: @HopDavid While I agree with your orbital mechanics I don't see how it's relevant to the scenario.  A head-on impact requires a perihelion at 1AU and that can't happen without the object starting with a velocity normal to the direction to the sun.

Comment: @LorenPechtel You don't seem to have a grasp of what Vinf is. At infinity a parabolic orbit's velocity would be zero. At a finite distance it's  escape velocity. Escape velocity approaches zero as r goes to infinity. A parabola's velocity vector can point any direction. If the magnititude of it's velocity vector is sqrt(2GM/r), it's a parabolic orbit with Vinf = 0.

Comment: @HopDavid If it's Vinf is zero why would it not head straight for the sun?

Comment: @LorenPechtel (sigh…) Once again direction doesn't matter. An escape orbit with Vinf = zero need only have velocity vector with magnitude of sqrt(2GM/r). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_trajectory

Answer (score 5):

Answer for less science savvy readers:

If both planets are the same weight and size, and almost touch each other, it should be intuitive that at the point where they touch there is zero gravity, since the pull towards either planet cancels out each other. If it's not yet intuitive: imagine you are near where the 2 planets touch and you fall down - how can you tell towards which of the 2 planets you would fall? You can't.

The circumference of the earth is about 40'000 kilometers, and it rotates about once every 24 hours. So at the equator the speed due to rotation is about 40'000/24=1'666 km/h, and the one thing holding the planet together was gravity. Imagine swinging a ball on a long string at 1666 km/h and letting go.

Rocks (a.k.a. continents) and everything else, like air and water, will fall off of each planet, and either fly into space or bombard the other planet. For comparison, in an extremely strong tornado, air moves at 600 km/h and flattens buildings, now we have air, water, and mountains, moving at 1666 km/h and more. Once anything impacts the other planet, it becomes part of the other planet's surface. From there it will fly off again, for the same reasons it flew off from the first planet. No matter where you are, you either get squished or you get to see space - and probably get squished once you collide with other space rocks.

**Time to start colonizing mars**, and hope the debris doesn't impact too hard there. Maybe it would be safer to colonize a moon of one of the gas giants instead, because they are further away.